# Getting X and Y Co-ordinates in rotation animation in Android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-canvas

```
    Is there any better way to get x and y co-ordinates of a view if the view is set to animate for a few seconds in a clockwise direction.


@Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("Anim", "Anim started");  




            float g = wheelMenu.getX();
            float h = wheelMenu.getY();

            }


            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("Anim", "Anim ended");

                float i = wheelMenu.getX();
                float j = wheelMenu.getY();


            }



            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("Anim", "Anim started");

                float k = wheelMenu.getX();
                float l = wheelMenu.getY();



            }
```

Iam using below code to get X,Y co-ordinates. The requirement is to rotate a view in circular fashion and listener to capture the motion event to get XY coordinates along the animation path.

Comment: Better way than what? Show us some `not so better` code?

Comment: @Skynet updated the question just now

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but still deserves an answer. An alternative way of getting the coordinates of a view is using `getGlobalVisibleRect`, which will get you the rectangle of the view relative to the root/top-parent view.
e.g.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view_id);
Rect view_rect = new Rect();
textView.getGlobalVisibleRect(view_rect);
int x = view_rect.left;
int y = view_rect.top;
```

I am not sure whether there will be a significant delay between getting the rectangle and movement of the view, since there is an animation running. However this would be minimised by having few parent views of your view.

Your question seems unclear whether you want to retrieve coordinates of a motion event or a view, as the code of motion is mentioned. Please comment below and/or adjust your question if this is the case.